# Counting the number of times same record exist in a given period of time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query to find out whether a record exist more than one or not in a given period of time. And even if it exist, how many times the same record has been repeated.

Now to solve this issue, I have sorted the records.

```
select * from table_name where date = ? and date > ? order by email
```

And trying to count the number of times the same record exist.But I am not able to figure out a way to count the number of times the same record exists.

Here is a problem.The image below holds the basic data structure.
[image]

Here is the expected output for a year
[image]

The table above holds `Xyz` name and `xyz@email.com` data three times. And the name `Abc` and email `abc@email.com` two times and the third record name `Def` and email `def@email.com` two times. Now what I am trying to figure out a way to find out the number of times each records are being repeated in a given period of time using a single query. I am thinking to make use of recursion on a record and count till it didn't find a different record after sorting it. But using recursion on every records seems expensive.

Is there a better solution to solve this problem ?

Regards

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected . result  ..

Comment: Since you want to COUNT something, have you considered researching the COUNT function in Postgres?

Comment: Have you tried  grouping and counting?
`select column, count(column) from tabel where date between dateIni and dateEnd group by column` ?

Comment: @dfundako I am aware of COUNT but the problem here is you count data is not fixed means what you are trying to count

Comment: Sounds like the very basic record counting. Can't understand from the question what the complexity is.

Comment: Wait lemme update the question once again

Comment: Show some example data. A few rows will suffice.

Comment: @scaisEdge question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group and count.

```
SELECT column_to_compare1, column_to_compare2, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE [date] BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
GROUP BY column_to_compare1, column_to_compare2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- IF YOU WANT TO ONLY INCLUDE RECORDS WITH DUPLICATES
```

Between is inclusive, so you can adjust your dates with DATEADD if you really want between.

Comment: This is not valid Postgres syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COUNT function to do this.

To do this using your own query:

```
SELECT Name, Email, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM table_name 
WHERE date BETWEEN '01/01/2005' AND '31/12/2005'
GROUP BY Name, Email
```

However your example query is poor so I cannot give you a better solution. Here is an example of this working: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cdad6/2)

**EDIT**: Updated my solution to match you expected output.

Comment: @Lokesh There is no further complexity. You can just add the range of dates into the WHERE clause. I've updated my example

Comment: Your condition is only limited to `'%Ro%'` but I am trying to count the number of times each and every records exist

Comment: @Lokesh that was an example. Unless you also have a database of films and are trying to search for film titles that contain 'Ro', then I don't recommend using it! The point of the example was to demonstrate the functionality you need, specifically the COUNT function and the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Lokesh I've removed that condition from the fiddle to avoid any further misunderstanding.